# Dynamically appending to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, hdfstore

I have been playing with Pandas to get HTTP logs into Pandas for analysis as it is a good source of large volumes of data and will allow me to learn Pandas.

I get the logs streamed in one line at a time and therefore can not import from CSV and need to 'pump' these into a Pandas DataFrame, which I will then persist to a HDFStore file.

The code I have written at the moment does read from a GZIP just so I can get the process going, but once I have the Panda's bit done I will modify it to be event driven with a pubsub style co-routine.

Here is my code so far:

```
    import os
    import gzip, io
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    def read_gzip(file):        
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(file)):
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                while True:
                    for line in io.BufferedReader(gzip.open(file)):
                        yield line

    class ElbParser(object):

        def __init__(self, file):
            self.file = file

        def get_log_lines(self):
            return read_gzip(self.file)

        def build_series(self, log_line):

            def normalise_ip(input_string):
                try:
                    text = input_string.split(':')[0]
                except:
                    text = np.NaN
                finally:
                    return text

            def normalise_time(input_string):
                try:
                    text = float(input_string)
                except:
                    text = np.NaN
                finally:
                    return text

            def normalise_ints(input_string):
                try:
                    text = int(input_string)
                except:
                    text = np.NaN
                finally:
                    return text

            log_list = log_line.split()
            elb_series = pd.Series({
                    'timestamp' : np.datetime64(log_list[0]),
                    'elb_name' : log_list[1],

                    'client_ip' : normalise_ip(log_list[2]),
                    'backend_ip' : normalise_ip(log_list[3]),

                    'request_processing_time' : normalise_time(log_list[4]),
                    'backend_processing_time' : normalise_time(log_list[5]),
                    'response_processing_time' : normalise_time(log_list[6]),

                    'elb_status_code' : normalise_ints(log_list[7]),
                    'backend_status_code' : normalise_ints(log_list[8]),

                    'received_bytes' : normalise_ints(log_list[9]),
                    'sent_bytes' : normalise_ints(log_list[10]),

                    'http_method' : log_list[11].strip("'").strip('"'),
                    'request' : log_list[13].strip("'").strip('"')
                    })

            return elb_series
```

The following is the basic test code for exercising the above code:

```
    import os
    import sys
    import unittest
    import pandas as pd

    from lbreader import ElbParser

    test_elb_log_file = 'tests/resources/lb_log.gz'

    class ElbTest(unittest.TestCase):

        #
        # Fixture Framework
        #

        def setUp(self):
            print '\nTest Fixture setUp'
            self.elbparser = ElbParser(test_elb_log_file)


        def tearDown(self):
            print '\nTest Fixture tearDown'
            del self.elbparser

        #
        # Tests
        #

        def test_01_get_aws_elb_log_line(self):
            print '\n running get aws elb log line'
            log_lines = self.elbparser.get_log_lines()
            self.failUnlessEqual('2014-05-15T23:00:04.696671Z poundlb 192.168.0.10:53345 - -1 -1 -1 408 408 55 0 "PUT https://localhost:443/private/urls HTTP/1.1"\n'
                             , log_lines.next())

        def test_02_build_series_with_aws_elb_log_line(self):
            print '\n running build series from elb log'
            log_lines = self.elbparser.get_log_lines()
            test = self.elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
            test_line_dict = {'backend_ip': '-',
                              'backend_processing_time': -1.0,
                              'backend_status_code': 408,
                              'client_ip': '192.168.0.10',
                              'lb_name': 'poundlb',
                              'elb_status_code': 408,
                              'http_method': 'PUT',
                              'received_bytes': 55,
                              'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
                              'request_processing_time': -1.0,
                              'response_processing_time': -1.0,
                              'sent_bytes': 0,
                              'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:04.696671+0100')}
            self.failUnlessEqual(test_line_dict, test.to_dict())


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Now to where I seem to have managed to get stuck:

I am able to create pandas.Series data, but when I try to push it into a dataframe it takes it in as two columns of 11 rows.

```
    test.values
    >>> array(['-', -1.0, 408, '192.168.0.10', 'poundlb', 408, 'PUT', 55,
   'HTTP/1.1', -1.0, -1.0, 0,
   numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:04.696671+0100')], dtype=object)


    df = pd.DataFrame(test.values.tolist(), column_list)
    >>> df
    Out[35]: 
                                                            0
    backend_ip                                              -
    backend_processing_time                                -1
    backend_status_code                                   408
    client_ip                                    192.168.0.10
    elb_name                                          poundlb
    elb_status_code                                       408
    http_method                                           PUT
    received_bytes                                         55
    request                                          HTTP/1.1
    request_processing_time                                -1
    response_processing_time                               -1
    sent_bytes                                              0
    timestamp                 2014-05-16T00:00:04.696671+0100

    [13 rows x 1 columns]
```

This is far from what I was hoping to get, I was hoping for [1 rows x 1 columns]:

```
                 backend_ip   backend_processing_time backend_status_code   backend_status_code  client_ip     elb_name  elb_status_code  http_method  received_bytes  request   request_processing_time   response_processing_time   sent_bytes  timestamp                    
    0            -            -1                      408                   408                  192.168.0.10  poundlb   408              PUT          55              HTTP/1.1  -1                        -1                         0           2014-05-16T00:00:04
    1            -            -1                      408                   408                  192.168.0.11  poundlb   408              PUT          55              HTTP/1.1  -1                        -1                         0           2014-05-16T00:00:05
    2            -            -1                      408                   408                  192.168.0.12  poundlb   408              PUT          55              HTTP/1.1  -1                        -1                         0           2014-05-16T00:00:06
```

Such that if I added another pandas.Series log line, I would get another row and so on. 
I also intend to index on the following: timestamp, client_ip, backend_ip

I would really appreciate some assistance with this as I don't seem to be getting my rows/columns correct.

After a bit of playing around I got the following:
So after playing a bit with this I came up with the following, but still can not concatinate/append.

```
    >>> test0 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test1 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test2 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test3 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test4 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test5 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test6 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test7 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test8 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test9 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test10 = elbparser.build_series(log_lines.next())
    >>> test_list = [test.to_dict(), test1.to_dict(), test2.to_dict(), test3.to_dict(), test4.to_dict(), test5.to_dict(), test6.to_dict(), test7.to_dict(), test8.to_dict(), test9.to_dict(), test10.to_dict()]
    >>> test_list
    [{'backend_ip': '-',
      'backend_processing_time': -1.0,
      'backend_status_code': 408,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.1',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 408,
      'http_method': 'PUT',
      'received_bytes': 55,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': -1.0,
      'response_processing_time': -1.0,
      'sent_bytes': 0,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:04.696671+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.241',
      'backend_processing_time': 59.246736,
      'backend_status_code': 403,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.2',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 403,
      'http_method': 'PUT',
      'received_bytes': 55,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 3.4e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 2.9e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 64,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:30.980494+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.242',
      'backend_processing_time': 59.42053,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.3',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'PUT',
      'received_bytes': 173,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 8.4e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 6.9e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 149,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:32.687835+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.39',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.016443,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.4',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'GET',
      'received_bytes': 0,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 7.9e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 4e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 289,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:38.247760+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.41',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.008624,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.5',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'GET',
      'received_bytes': 0,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 5.4e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 3.2e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 200,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:38.432535+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.43',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.138925,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.6',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'GET',
      'received_bytes': 0,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 4.5e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 4.3e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 268,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:38.509598+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.38',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.013578,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.7',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'POST',
      'received_bytes': 291,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 4.2e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 2.7e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 36,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:38.667479+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.42',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.017493,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.8',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'GET',
      'received_bytes': 0,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 3.7e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 2.7e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 290,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:38.708697+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.40',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.014167,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.9',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'POST',
      'received_bytes': 297,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 3.5e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 2.7e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 36,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:38.746867+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.40',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.094383,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0.10',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'PUT',
      'received_bytes': 79,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 3.4e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 3.6e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 148,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:39.333482+0100')},
     {'backend_ip': '10.0.0.42',
      'backend_processing_time': 0.061355,
      'backend_status_code': 200,
      'client_ip': '192.168.0,10',
      'elb_name': 'poundlb',
      'elb_status_code': 200,
      'http_method': 'PUT',
      'received_bytes': 79,
      'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
      'request_processing_time': 9.6e-05,
      'response_processing_time': 5.8e-05,
      'sent_bytes': 148,
      'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:39.345097+0100')}]


    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(test.to_dict(), index_list)
    >>> df
    Out[45]: 
                             backend_ip  backend_processing_time  
    backend_ip                        -                       -1   
    backend_processing_time           -                       -1   
    backend_status_code               -                       -1   
    client_ip                         -                       -1   
    elb_name                          -                       -1   
    elb_status_code                   -                       -1   
    http_method                       -                       -1   
    received_bytes                    -                       -1   
    request                           -                       -1   
    request_processing_time           -                       -1   
    response_processing_time          -                       -1   
    sent_bytes                        -                       -1   
    timestamp                         -                       -1   

                              backend_status_code       client_ip  
    backend_ip                                408  192.168.0.10   
    backend_processing_time                   408  192.168.0.10   
    backend_status_code                       408  192.168.0.10   
    client_ip                                 408  192.168.0.10   
    elb_name                                  408  192.168.0.10   
    elb_status_code                           408  192.168.0.10   
    http_method                               408  192.168.0.10   
    received_bytes                            408  192.168.0.10   
    request                                   408  192.168.0.10   
    request_processing_time                   408  192.168.0.10   
    response_processing_time                  408  192.168.0.10   
    sent_bytes                                408  192.168.0.10   
    timestamp                                 408  192.168.0.10   

                                     elb_name  elb_status_code http_method  
    backend_ip                poundlb              408         PUT   
    backend_processing_time   poundlb              408         PUT   
    backend_status_code       poundlb              408         PUT   
    client_ip                 poundlb              408         PUT   
    elb_name                  poundlb              408         PUT   
    elb_status_code           poundlb              408         PUT   
    http_method               poundlb              408         PUT   
    received_bytes            poundlb              408         PUT   
    request                   poundlb              408         PUT   
    request_processing_time   poundlb              408         PUT   
    response_processing_time  poundlb              408         PUT   
    sent_bytes                poundlb              408         PUT   
    timestamp                 poundlb              408         PUT   

                              received_bytes   request  request_processing_time  
    backend_ip                            55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    backend_processing_time               55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    backend_status_code                   55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    client_ip                             55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    elb_name                              55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    elb_status_code                       55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    http_method                           55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    received_bytes                        55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    request                               55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    request_processing_time               55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    response_processing_time              55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    sent_bytes                            55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   
    timestamp                             55  HTTP/1.1                       -1   

                              response_processing_time  sent_bytes  
    backend_ip                                      -1           0   
    backend_processing_time                         -1           0   
    backend_status_code                             -1           0   
    client_ip                                       -1           0   
    elb_name                                        -1           0   
    elb_status_code                                 -1           0   
    http_method                                     -1           0   
    received_bytes                                  -1           0   
    request                                         -1           0   
    request_processing_time                         -1           0   
    response_processing_time                        -1           0   
    sent_bytes                                      -1           0   
    timestamp                                       -1           0   

                                              timestamp  
    backend_ip               2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    backend_processing_time  2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    backend_status_code      2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    client_ip                2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    elb_name                 2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    elb_status_code          2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    http_method              2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    received_bytes           2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    request                  2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    request_processing_time  2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    response_processing_time 2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    sent_bytes               2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  
    timestamp                2014-05-15 23:00:04.696671  

    [13 rows x 13 columns]
```

Which is what I want, but I still seem to have a problem with appending/concatenating after this.

I will investigate the solution from

Comment: It is important to note that whatever solution you find to append to your dataframe, you will not be able to avoid a full copy of your dataframe unless you have preallocated memory by defining an empty frame of sufficient size which you fill up sequentially. Everybody, please correct me if I am wrong about this and how appending would be possible without preallocation in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
# Create a data dict
test_line_dict = {'backend_ip': '-',
                  'backend_processing_time': -1.0,
                  'backend_status_code': 408,
                  'client_ip': '192.168.0.10',
                  'lb_name': 'poundlb',
                  'elb_status_code': 408,
                  'http_method': 'PUT',
                  'received_bytes': 55,
                  'request': 'HTTP/1.1',
                  'request_processing_time': -1.0,
                  'response_processing_time': -1.0,
                  'sent_bytes': 0,
                  'timestamp': numpy.datetime64('2014-05-16T00:00:04.696671+0100')}
# Create the corresponding dataframe
idOfTheFirstElement = '1st'
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({idOfTheFirstElement:test_line_dict})
# Transpose the result
df = df.T
# One can dynamically append/add new rows with pd.concat
dfNew = pd.concat([df,df,df])
```

Comment: Hi Guillaume,

Thanks for your response, I really appreciate the quick turnaround. I will give it a go and see if I can get the concatenation working as you have suggested.
Should I be concerned about speed of concatenation as I am going to be adding about 1.2Billion requests per day, .... should I possibly be looking at appends?
Note I will be looking to frequently marshal the data to HDFStore and to disk, possibly every 50,000 requests.. and I am worried about the time this will take.
Each days logs will be stored and a new HDFStore file created the system crosses midnight.

Comment: I guess you will have to play with %timeit in ipython to see the time needed to perform operation
In [39]: %timeit pd.concat([df,df,df])
1000 loops, best of 3: 554 µs per loop