# adding data pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need a pandas dataframe in order to pass values to bokeh.

```
df2 = DataFrame(data=mia_classe,columns=['classe','media','deviazione'])
for classe in Classe.objects.all():
    risposte = Risposta.objects.filter(prova__classe=classe).values_list('score', flat=True)
    df2.append({'classe': classe,'media':media(risposte)*10,'deviazione':sigma(risposte)*10}, ignore_index=True)
print df2
```

This code doesn't return an error, but the dataframe is empty.
Afret reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745785/dynamically-appending-to-a-pandas-dataframe) I tried this way too:

```
mia_classe = defaultdict(list)
df2 = DataFrame(data=mia_classe,columns=['classe','media','deviazione'])
for classe in Classe.objects.all():
    risposte = Risposta.objects.filter(prova__classe=classe).values_list('score', flat=True)
    mia_classe = {'classe': classe,'media':media(risposte)*10,'deviazione':deviazione_standard(risposte)*10}
    new_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(mia_classe)
    df2.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)
print df2
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/allora/testingresso/testingresso/estraicoras.py", line 30, in <module>
    new_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(mia_classe)
  File "//anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 804, in from_dict
    return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "//anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 226, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "//anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 363, in _init_dict
dtype=dtype)
  File "//anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5158, in _arrays_to_mgr
index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "//anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5197, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `orient='index'`:

```
new_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(mia_classe, orient='index')
```

Using an improvised example:

```
mia_classe = {'classe': 'classe','media': 100,'deviazione': 150}
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mia_classe, orient='index')

                 0
classe      classe
deviazione     150
media          100
```

Comment: thank you! unfortunately a need exactly the columns order. The problem is with the appending method.

Comment: The error you posted originated in the `.from_dict()` part, not in the `.append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the append method. I misunderstood the pandas reference.
Here how I solved (with the help of a colleague of mine):

```
mio_dict = {'nome': [],'media':[],'deviazione':[]}                                                    
for classe in Classe.objects.all():
    risposte = Risposta.objects.filter(prova__classe=classe).values_list('score', flat=True)
    mio_dict['nome'].append(u"%s - %s" % (classe.sezione, classe.scuola.nome))
    mio_dict['media'].append(media(risposte)*10)
    mio_dict['deviazione'].append(sigma(risposte)*10)

mio_df = pandas.DataFrame(mio_dict)
print mio_df
```

so, basically I could solve the problem changing the point of view: instead appending every class with its name, average and standard deviation, appending every name to other names, every avg with other avg etcetera.

The result sounds like this:

```
    deviazione     media                             nome
0     3.841544  7.614035        1A - piazzi lena perpenti
1     4.457753  6.807576                  1A - otto marzo
2     4.001645  7.602469                 1F - g. ferraris
3     4.133874  7.241026                 1M - g. ferraris
4     4.494765  7.149123       1BS - piazzi lena perpenti
```